# need to check which cacerts and jks, Application deployed on weblogic programs is using from backend [linux Server]

Tags: weblogic, jks, cacerts

In my weblogic console, i am seeing location of identity, truststore and cacerts. But there are some other cacerts which Apps running in Weblogic is using. Is there any command in linux to check which all cacerts and keystore location is in use. As below location cacerts is used by Apps running on weblogic, but not mentioned anywhere in weblogic console.

```
[prdzap@vmtlxap security]$ ls
 tsscacerts_fde tsscacerts_ret yutz_prod.jks tsscacerts 
[prdzap@vmtlxap security]$ pwd
/app/domains/prdzap/PRDZAP/security
```

Answer (score 1):

As i found the solution myself, so thought of updating [So that it will help others].

To search any jks file even if its extenetion is changed globally [As below files]

```
[prdzap@vmtlxap security]$ ls
 tsscacerts_fde tsscacerts_ret yutz_prod.jks tsscacerts
```

We can use the combination of "find","file" and "grep" command

```
[prdzap@vmtlxap security]$ file tsscacerts_fde
tsscacerts_fde: Java KeyStore

[prdzap@vmtlxap security]$ find . -type f  -exec file {} \; | grep -i "Java KeyStore"
./tsscacerts_fde: Java KeyStore 
./tsscacerts_ret: Java KeyStore 
./yutz_prod.jks: Java KeyStore 
./tsscacerts: Java KeyStore
```